# Problems with object collision detection using mesh colliders in unity

Tags: unity, c#, mesh, collider

So I'm working on a project and I need to detect when an empty object with a mesh attached to it collides with another object. Essentially, I want to know when the mesh is touching a cube. I've tried using the mesh collider (And it works) but the problem is: I have a circular mesh and therefore need to Inflate the mesh. This 
decreases its accuracy and increases lag by a lot and I can't have that happen.

TL;DR: I copy my mesh to a mesh collider but the mesh collider is inaccurate and laggy for collision detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simplified version of the mesh with less vertices and faces used for collision. This will give you better performance. If it works for the shape of the mesh, making the mesh collider convex makes it faster. If the object is too complicated to represent accurately using a single convex mesh, you can try to use multiple convex meshes approximate the shape.